# Configure "Hangfire.Net" in .NET Core console application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, hangfire

I am creating a console application in which I need to perform some tasks in parallel so I am trying to use Hangfire.Net.

Can anyone please suggest me how to configure Hangfire.Net in .NET Core console application?

Comment: in general, this [hangfire documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-console-app.html) is still valid for .NET Core. Try it and post a question with the specific problem if you face one. Sorry, but right now this is an off-topic, as you ask for some kind of tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration of Hangfire in .Net Core is quite state forward This will store it in the database.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("connection_string");

using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
     Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Code ripped from [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-console-app.html)

Comment: he wants to do this in console app, not web

Comment: My bad i miss understood as all .net core applications are console applications.   I have edited the answer.